# How to use Eclipse plugin tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar

Tags: eclipse, jar

I want to know how to run/use the following Eclipse plugin which I've downloaded:

There is a project from a guy called 'tarlog' that made a plugin for eclipse at this google code site: http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads/detail?name=tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar&can=2&q=

It has some other features for eclipse, amongst which is Ctrl++ and Ctrl+- to change the font size.

I've tried Run>External Tools>External Tools Configurations. I put C:\Users\User\workspace\tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar as the Location and C:\Users\User\workspace (the folder containing the file) as the Working Directory. Thi results in the following error:

Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\workspace\tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar" (in directory "C:\Users\User\workspace"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

This is puzzling since I'm running 64 bit windows. Just wondering how to run/use the plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a regular eclipse plugin.

It should be enough for you to:

1) Copy the `.jar` in the `dropins\plugins` folder in the folder where you've installed eclipse; create the folders if they don't exist already.

NOTE: this is the eclipse install path (`[Eclipse path]\dropins\plugins`), and NOT the workspace you're working in.

2) Restart Eclipse.

That's it, your plugin is good to go.

Comment: the Eclipse folder doesn't seem to have \dropins

Comment: @bluesh34 Create new folders if they don't exist. The path should look like `eclipse\dropins\plugins\plugin_name.jar`

Comment: actually, it does have the \plugins folder, it's just I couldn't see it using 7-zip in the location I'd put it. i'll give your answer a try now, Godwilling

Comment: Eclipse places plugins you install from within the Eclipse UI in its `\plugins` folder. You should place plugin .jars you manually copy in `\dropins\plugins`. It's just a convention, which makes updating them easier.

Comment: I just followed your answer: I had to create a plugins folder as there wasn't one. I restarted Eclipse and tried to run the file uing Run>External Tools>External Tools Configurations. I got the following error: Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\eclipse-java-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\plugins\tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: You're not supposed to try running the .jar, just open Eclipse.exe; it will automatically load the plugin.

Comment: I tried that too- the plugin is supposed to allow you to increase/decrease font size using crtl + + or ctrl + mousewheel, but neither works

Comment: Well that's possibly because the path you posted is `plugins\plugins`, not `dropins\plugins`. Put it there then try again.

Comment: changed it but same results :(

Comment: Are you sure you followed the steps exactly? I'm also running KeplerSR1 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, and (just tried pulling the plugin in) it works perfectly fine on my machine. Make sure that you've restarted Eclipse, and that that's the exact name of the path you use, as Eclipse only ever looks for plugins in `\dropins\plugins` and `\plugins`.

Comment: oh, sorry I did dropins\plugins- somehow my eclipse isn't working anymore- seems like someone's playing a practical joke on me sometimes :(

Comment: ok- it's working now thanks. how to use it is another question ctrl - works but ctrl + doesn't

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38438/discussion-between-bluesh34-and-blgt)

Comment: This method does not work with Eclipse Neon version, because in Neon, Ctrl+'+' (not on the Numpad) for zooming in and Ctrl+'-' for zooming out have been the build-in feature. Installing another conflicting plugin will break the functionality of the original eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The Tarlog Plugin needs the Java Development Tools (JDT) intalled. This is important in case you prefer to work with a version of Eclipse that is designed for non-Java development, e.g. PHP development.

In my case tarlog wasn't recognized at Eclipse startup.

So I've installed  JDT via Eclipse Marketplace.

If you don't have JDT, the plugin can't be recognized, see logfile:

```
  !MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from tarlog.eclipse.plugins 1.4.2 to bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.4.0.

 /home/knb/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1.v20160907-1200/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/opt/eclipse/php-neon/eclipse/.options loaded
Time to load bundles: 51
..
[p2] Mon Nov 14 10:05:24 CET 2016 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 50199877-49aa-0016-1ecb-d3e3ab767be8] [reconciler] No extra requirements.
!SESSION 2016-11-14 10:05:19.506 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx3072m eclipse
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx3072m eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug /opt/eclipse/php-neon/eclipse/.options

[p2] Mon Nov 14 10:05:24 CET 2016 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 50199877-49aa-0016-1ecb-d3e3ab767be8] [reconciler] [plan] 
Some units will not be installed, because they are already installed or there are dependency issues:
tarlog.eclipse.plugins 1.4.2
!MESSAGE Problems resolving provisioning plan.
!MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from tarlog.eclipse.plugins 1.4.2 to 
bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 0.0.0.
!MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from tarlog.eclipse.plugins 1.4.2 to 
bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.4.0.
```